# bootstrap wysihtml5 is not working in IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, load, editor, wysihtml5

In rails 3.2.9, i am using bootstrap's wysihtml5 editor to one textarea field but in IE9 i am not getting that field's(textarea) value. I am loading a form via ajax to preview this text field's details before saving it. In IE-10 it is working fine.

In application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
```

In application.css

```
*= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
```

While serializing the form i am not getting text field's value

```
form_data = jQuery("#form_id").serialize();
jQuery.ajax({type :'POST', url : '/user/preview.js?', data : form_data});
```

In views,

```
<%= f.input :description, :as=>:text, :label =>false, :required => false, :placeholder=>"Description", :input_html=>{:rows=>"10", :class=>"texteditor", :style=>"width: 520px;"} %>
```

In script,

```
function loadTextEditor(){
   $('.texteditor').wysihtml5();
}
window.onload = loadTextEditor();
```

How do i get texteditor's value before saving it via ajax. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to look the error on `inspect element > console`?

Comment: I thinks it has an issue on IE.. check this out:

https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/84

Comment: This link contains with different issues, mine is different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the editor object to get the value of the textarea:

```
$('.texteditor').data("wysihtml5").editor.getValue();
```